# Is storing passwords in encrypted container still bad practice?

Tags: encryption, passwords, password-management, account-security, veracrypt

Suppose I need to store a bunch of passwords: storing them in a *txt* or *odt* file inside an encrypted container, such as the ones produced by VeraCrypt, is bad practice? Would I put myself at risk?

If so what are my other free options? (So no password managers) Do I need to also hash my passwords before storing them in the encrypted container? Would a physical copy of the list be more secure? Or is there some other option that I didn't consider? (Of course the option of just remembering them is not implementable)

Comment: This is the exact use case for a password manager; why would you want to reinvent this? Also, if you hashed the passwords, how would you ever read them again?

Comment: You asked for free options and added "so no password managers", but remember that free and open source password managers exist (for example KeePass). It is ok to implement your own methods for managing passwords, but remember they will have shortcomings. For example, the most annoying thing about storing passwords in a document is that they will be visible once you open it (so it's vulnerable to shoulder surfing).